# Add jQuery hover effect across two tables

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have two HTML tables in `div`s floated next to each other. The second `div` is scrollable in the horizontal direction, so in effect it looks like one big table where the first few columns are 'frozen' and the others can be scrolled.

The following jQuery works great to highlight a row in one table when the user hovers over it:

```
$("table.grid tr:not(:first-child)")
  .hover(
    function () { $(this).addClass("highlight"); },
    function () { $(this).removeClass("highlight"); }
  );
```

Note that the `:not(:first-child)` prevents the header being highlighted.

How can I amend this so that it also highlights the corresponding row in the other table (which also has a class of `grid`)?

In other words, if I hover over the `n`th row in either table, then the `n`th rows in both tables are highlighted.

**EDIT**: The HTML looks like:

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left">
    <table id="names" class="grid">
      <tr><th>Last</th><th>First</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Smith</td><td>John</td></tr>
      <!-- etc -->
      </table>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; overflow-x: scroll">
    <table id="results" class="grid">
      <tr><th>Test 1</th><th>Test 2</th></tr>
      <tr><td>50%</td><td>70%</td></tr>
      <!-- etc -->
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to grab all the `<tr>`s at the beginning and then combine [`$(this).index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), and `:nth-child` to select the right rows in both tables at once:

```
var $trs = $('table.grid tr:not(:first-child)');
$trs.hover(
    function() {
        var i = $(this).index() + 1;
        $trs.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('highlight');
    },
    function() {
        var i = $(this).index() + 1;
        $trs.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').removeClass('highlight');
    }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/54thG/

The `index` call gives you the position of the `<tr>` being hovered with respect to its siblings in `$trs`, then you adjust by 1 because `index` is zero-based but `:nth-child` (being a CSS selector) is one-based, and fiddle with the class on both rows at once.

Comment: The 10 minutes I spent preparing an answer of my own wasn't totally wasted; the 'filter' part was the missing piece I got to learn from mu's answer, which as the fiddle shows is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I figured out:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <style>
    .highlight {background:gray;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="float: left">
                <table id="names" class="grid" style="width:200px">
                    <tr class="row0"><th style="width:40%">Last</th><th>First</th></tr>
                    <tr class="row1"><td>Smith</td><td>John</td></tr>
                    <tr class="row2"><td>Smith</td><td>John</td></tr>
                    <tr class="row3"><td>Smith</td><td>John</td></tr>
                    <tr class="row4"><td>Smith</td><td>John</td></tr>
                    <!-- etc -->
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; overflow-x: scroll">
                <table id="results" class="grid" style="width:200px">
                    <tr class="row0"><th>Test 1</th><th>Test 2</th></tr>
                    <tr class="row1"><td>50%</td><td>70%</td></tr>
                    <tr class="row2"><td>50%</td><td>70%</td></tr>
                    <tr class="row3"><td>50%</td><td>70%</td></tr>
                    <!-- etc -->
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table#names tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(k, v){
        var self = this;
        // index: 0 = second row; 1= 3rd row... of table#names 
        // index+1 for other table's row: .find('tr.row'+(index+1))
        (function(index){ 
            $(self).hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");                

                    // go up to parent div of #names, then its siblings, then the siblings' table's row
                    // you could also just $('table#results')
                    $('table#names').parent().siblings().find('tr.row'+(index+1)).addClass("highlight");
                }, function() {
  $('table#names').parent().siblings().find('tr.row'+(index+1)).removeClass("highlight");
                    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
                }
            );
        })(k); // pass index so function above remembers it
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6aNy2/