# jQuery need help selecting tr elements inside a div element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover, kendo-ui-grid

I'm trying to build a custom hover event using Kendo UI Grid control. I'm having issues getting the entire row to highlight on mouseover when using locked columns. I have not been able to find a straightforward example to follow.

Currently the selection on hover looks like this:

[image: unlocked grid section mouseover]

[image: locked grid section mouseover]

I've written the following function to try and highlight the entire row (locked and unlocked sections) but I can't seem to get the correct jQuery selector:

```
$("#ddhintgrid div.k-grid-content table tbody tr").hover(function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
        var grid = $("#ddhintgrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var rowUid = grid.dataItem(this).uid;

            // select the row currently being edited
        $('[data-uid=' +rowUid + ']').addClass('k-state-hover');
    },
    function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
        $("#ddhintgrid .k-state-hover").removeClass("k-state-hover");
    });
```

The contents of this method is unimportant. I simply want it to trigger when the user moves the mouse over a row in the unlocked portion of the grid.

The element I want the .hover() function to fire on is the tr element under the `<div class="k-grid-content>` element. See here:

[image: DOM Explorer]

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by modifying the solution found here: [Add jQuery hover effect across two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898430/add-jquery-hover-effect-across-two-tables).

I added the following code to dataBound function of the dataSource for my grid:

```
var $trs = $('table.k-selectable tbody tr');
$trs.hover(
    function () {
        var i = $(this).index() +1;
        $trs.filter(':nth-child(' +i + ')').addClass('k-state-hover');
    },
    function () {
        var i = $(this).index() +1;
        $trs.filter(':nth-child(' +i + ')').removeClass('k-state-hover');
    }
);
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else having this issue. Haven't noticed any problems yet.

Comment: Placing the function within the dataBound parameter is what fixed it for me. `dataBound: function() {$('.hover').hover(function(e) {hover($(this),e);});}`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
$("#ddhintgrid > .k-grid-content > table > tbody > tr:not(:first, :last)").hover(function () {...});
```

You need to exclude the first and last (header and footer) tr's.

Also, you will need to iterate through the opposite table to find the associated row in order to set the CSS to "k-state-hover"/

Example:
I hover over row1 in the locked table, now the function should set the css for locked table row1 and find row1 in the "k-grid-content" table and also set the css for that row. The two rows will have different UID's so you can't rely on that for comparison, try n'th child or if you have a unique key for the rows data then you can use that to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly have the effect on sort etc. this has to be done in the `dataBound` event on the grid OR should be able to do it client side.  I did not test these but it should work.

### Client bound

You need to add a function to use toggling the class:

```
addHoverStyleToGridRow = function () {
    $("table.k-focusable tbody tr").hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("k-state-hover");
        }
    );
};
```

Then in the data bound:

```
// this is where the hover effect function is bound to grid
$("#ddhintgrid").kendoGrid({ dataBound: addHoverStyleToGridRow });
```

### Server bound

On the chance you are using server bound grid then this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#ddhintgrid").find("table.k-focusable tbody tr").hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("k-state-hover");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't work for me.

I have other stuff in my dataBound function but I added a call to addHoverStyleToGridRow() right at the top of it.